# pandas dataframe from nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following json as web api response:

```
{"prices": [
    {
     "start_date": "2016-07-06T00:00:00+02:00",
     "end_date": "2016-07-07T00:00:00+02:00",
     "values": [
    {
    "start_date": "2016-07-06T00:00:00+02:00",
    "end_date": "2016-07-06T00:30:00+02:00",
    "upward_weighted": 45.66,
    "downward_weighted": 20.63,
    "upward_marginal": 30.1,
    "downward_marginal": 12.8,
    "updated_date": "2016-07-07T15:45:36+02:00"
    },
    {
    "start_date": "2016-07-06T00:30:00+02:00",
    "end_date": "2016-07-06T01:00:00+02:00",
    "upward_weighted": 45.66,
    "downward_weighted": 20.63,
    "upward_marginal": 30.1,
    "downward_marginal": 12.8,
    "updated_date": "2016-07-07T15:45:36+02:00"
    }
    ]}
    ]}
```

And I would to retrieve the prices-> values as a Dataframe.

```
start_date|end_date|upward_weighted|downward_weighted|...|updated_date|
----------|--------|---------------|-----------------|---|------------|
xxxxxxx   |xxxxxxx |xxxxxxxx       |xxxxxxx          |   |xxxxxx      |
xxxxxxx   |xxxxxxx |xxxxxxxx       |xxxxxxx          |   |xxxxxx      |
```

When I try pandas.read_json(resp.content) I get a wrong dataframe containing only one column 'prices' with dict.

Is it possible to tell `pandas.read_json()` to make a DataFrame with prices->values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
df = json_normalize(d['prices'], 'values')
print (df)
   downward_marginal  downward_weighted                   end_date  \
0               12.8              20.63  2016-07-06T00:30:00+02:00   
1               12.8              20.63  2016-07-06T01:00:00+02:00   

                  start_date               updated_date  upward_marginal  \
0  2016-07-06T00:00:00+02:00  2016-07-07T15:45:36+02:00             30.1   
1  2016-07-06T00:30:00+02:00  2016-07-07T15:45:36+02:00             30.1   

   upward_weighted  
0            45.66  
1            45.66
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! But I don't get the point what is exactly doing json_normalize?

Answer (score 1):

please try this to solve your problem:
Get the values (from Price dictionary) in form of "list of dictionaries" from web api response:
such as values = [{}, {}] and pass it into pd dataframe.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(values)
 print(df)
```

you will get which u want. For More details http://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html